# Bots using internal wordpress search

Tags: search

My stats show that a lot of bots are abusing the internal wordpress search functionality of my site:

```
www.yinlingjiaoyu.cn
9
www.scckym.cn
9
www.gzcq1688.cn
9
www.mindswift.cn
8
www.ytgso.cn
8
www.annlin.cn
8
www.lfysjy.cn
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I.e. if a search begins with www. then block it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a security plugin which will do everything for you.
Like iThemes Security

> Bans troublesome user agents, bots and other hosts

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Comment: Is there a custom function I could use instead?